# How to get logged in user when user is authenticated using Google Openid connect?

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-openid, openid-connect

Im using Goolge openid connect for authenticating user in my application since openid 2.0 is deprecated by google.

When i make Google openid connect request, i get access token from which i get user details and save the user email in application session.
So im not using UserService in my approacht o login.

This approach is not providing me logged in user details, when i try the following code,

```
UserService userService=UserServiceFactory.gerUserService();
User user=userService.getCurrentUser();
```

In the above code, i get user as null even after user logged in into my application through openid connect.

So the problem is, i am not able to logout user also user is not getting logged out from my application even after logging out from Google.
User email is available in application session until user closes the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the page has been set to login: required in your app.yaml. Otherwise it seems to send NULL because the user hasn't explicitly given your page permission to see more info than the email.

Comment: My app is a domain app. So only user in my domain will access my app. When i set to login as u said, Google is asking consent from the user which ideally should not happen in domain apps. Because of this only i am using openid connect authorization to login my user. But in that case user is null in userservice.

Comment: Is it asking for them to login in again or just permission to access their information?

Comment: Unfortunately Google OpenID Connect is built on OAuth 2.0 which requires permission from the user before getting any information. https://developers.google.com/accounts/cookbook/technologies/OpenID-Connect     https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#consentpageexperience